# He was having his food when I went to his home. Or.... When I go to his home

Tags: past-tense

1. He was having his food **when** I went to his home.  Or....
2. He was eating his food **when** I go to his home.

Do I have to use comma before *when*?

3. He was eating his food**, when** I went to his home.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'He was eating when I went to his home' is a better version. Though both *having his food* and *eating his food* are correct, simply *eating* implies the latter anyways.
2. Also, 'when I **go** to his home' is incorrect. Since the first half of the sentence has a past tense 'He **was** eating', the second half should also maintain the same by 'when I **went** to his home'.
3. A Comma is unnecessary.

Comment: 'He was eating when I got to his home' would be the correct past-tense version of the sentence in 2.